# How to construct url in php?

Tags: php

I have a page named "career.php" that is built-in core PHP. I want its URL to be like `www.example.com/career` instead of `www.example.com/career.php`.
How can I do this in core PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a similar thing once so after researching I found that one way to do that is by editing the **.htacess** file which will hide the extension on filename like `www.example.com/index.html` `to www.example.com/index.`

Another way is using MVC frameworks like I use **LARAVEL** which has routes so in this case if you enter `www.example.com/career` then the `carrer.php` file will be rendered.